# displaying a text when JS button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a JavaScript button that generates a `GIFs` from `giphy.com` in order,
I tried to add a "Know more" Text displaying with `GIF` on button click
but apparently the button isn't working anymore.
 here is the code:

```js
var currImage = 0;
window.onload = () => {
    const factsArr = [
 { image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7aD5tv1ogNBtDhDi/giphy.gif', source:"Know more" },
 { image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/3ohhwJax6g4Y8BK30k/giphy.gif', source:"know more" },
  { image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/1nkUav308CBws/giphy.gif', source="Know more" },
    ];
  
    document.getElementById('source').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('generate-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
      
     document.getElementById('image').setAttribute('src', factsArr[currImage].image);
      currImage++;
      if (currImage == factsArr.length)
         currImage  = 0;
    })     
}
```

```html
<button id="generate-btn">Amazing Fact Button</button>
<img id="image"></img>
<div id="source"></div>
```

Comment: 3rd item in `factsArr`: `source=`, change to `source:`

Comment: Did you not check the console before posting?

Comment: its not clear where you intend to show the `...Know more...` text. Do clarify...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing some syntax and logical errors the code works. See comments in the code.

```js
var currImage = 0;
window.onload = () => {
    const factsArr = [
 { image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7aD5tv1ogNBtDhDi/giphy.gif', source:"Know more" },
 { image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/3ohhwJax6g4Y8BK30k/giphy.gif', source:"know more" },
  //{ image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/1nkUav308CBws/giphy.gif', source="Know more" }, syntax error "="
  { image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/1nkUav308CBws/giphy.gif', source:"Know more" },
    ];
  
    //document.getElementById('source').addEventListener('click', () => {
    //syntax error. arg list not closed
    //logical error. nothing to click on window.onload. next lines never executed
    /*
    document.getElementById('generate-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
      
     document.getElementById('image').setAttribute('src', factsArr[currImage].image);
      currImage++;
      if (currImage == factsArr.length)
         currImage  = 0;
    }) 
    */
    //corrected code
    const swtch = () => {
    document.getElementById('image').setAttribute('src', factsArr[currImage].image);
    document.getElementById('source').innerHTML=factsArr[currImage].source;
    currImage++;
    if (currImage == factsArr.length)
        currImage = 0;
    console.log(currImage);
};
document.getElementById('generate-btn').addEventListener('click', swtch);
document.getElementById('source').addEventListener('click', swtch);

}
```

```html
<button id="generate-btn">Amazing Fact Button</button>
<div id="source"></div>
<img id="image" /><!--</img> img is self-closing-->
```

Comment: Thanks so much man! this is my first project sorry if I bothered you with the codes.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work.  I only get 1 image of witches